# Cannot use callback in Google Maps script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Building the Google Maps `script` tag like this to be appended after the `div` has been rendered and then calling `initialize` which initializes the map like this fails because I have wrapped my code in an anonymous immediately invoked function expression...

```
(function(){
    var map,infoWindow;
   //lots of stuff...helper functions to initialize
   var initialize=function()
   {
       //init the map and infoWindow and other stuff here
       //manipulate the DOM here...
       //add controls that draw shapes on the map here...
   };
   
   var loadScript=function()
   var script=document.createElement('script');
   script.type='text/javascript';
   //cannot call initialize...
   script.src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&sensor=true&'+'libraries=geometry&'+'callback=initialize';
   document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    $("map-canvas").ready(loadScript);
})();
```

I get the error saying that the global object `initialize` could not be found.I would rather not unwrap initialize because it interacts directly with the `map` and `infoWindow` variables on many occassions.

## UPDATE:

I have also tried to use the following code:

```
var res=(function(){
    var map,infoWindow;
   //lots of stuff...helper functions to initialize
   var initialize=function()
   {
       //init the map and infoWindow and other stuff here
       //manipulate the DOM here...
       //add controls that draw shapes on the map here...
   };
   
   var loadScript=function()
   var script=document.createElement('script');
   script.type='text/javascript';
   //cannot call initialize...
   script.src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&sensor=true&'+'libraries=geometry&'+'callback=initialize';
   document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    return {init:initialize};
})();

var loadScript=function()
{
   var script=document.createElement('script');
   script.type='text/javascript';
   //cannot call initialize...
   script.src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&sensor=true&'+'libraries=geometry&'+'callback='+res.init;
document.body.appendChild(script);//line 509
};
$("map-canvas").ready(loadScript);
```

Now it says:

```
 GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=PART_OF_API_KEY%20and%20display%20on%20map...have%20to%20figure%20this%20one%20out...} 
 400  (Bad Request) gmaps.js:509
 loadScript gmaps.js:509
 c jquery-latest.js:3048
 p.fireWith jquery-latest.js:3160
 x.extend.ready jquery-latest.js:433
 q
```

Comment: Why don't you use good old way like in docs? Also you have a typo error in jquery selector of map div: `#map-canvas`.

Comment: @user3280126 not a typo,just ignorance...will fix that but i went back and found that it works even without the `#`...does jQuery search for any DOM element with a classname or id corresponding to the string I have sent???

Comment: @user3280126 are there any advantages of adding the script tag with the callback statically or will it be called before the DOM element is  ready.

Comment: For google maps script, it is best to write it statically. In most cases, scripts must be written statically. Otherwise, you should know well what you are doing.

Comment: @user3280126 Google demonstrate themselves [in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch) how to load the map dynamically. Loading it statically isn't the 'good old way', it's just one of the ways

Comment: @duncan That's true, it really depends on what you are dealing with. Also true that no _good old way_, I just tried to say that as to state as casual usage. And I asked why he was loading it async because of my curiosity.

Comment: @duncan I think keeping `loadScript` unexposed and exposing `initialize` which does not use any `named arguments` or the `arguments array-like-object` and only works with `functions` in the `module` and acts as a `closure` using the `variables` in the `module's` scope.It only initializes the `map` and `infoWindow` and adds a `dom element` to which it adds three other `dom elements` using pre-defined functions.would that be ok or could we change `callback` within script.src to talk to something inside the `module`?

Comment: @user3280126 I wanna use something like `node.js` `require` on the `client-side` and move a lot of code out of `index.js` and load them when and as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to attempt #1:

the scope of variables created in the self-executing function is the function. So when you use the `var`-keyword this variable will not be visible outside of the function.

Remove the var-keyword, and initialize will be global visible.

attempt #2 can't work, because  `res.init` is an object and not a string.